# how to multiplicate a list of integers in flutter

Tags: dart

is there any functions to do that?
i have a list and i want to multiplication each index of that list
for example

```
List<int> number = [1,2,3,4];
```

and the answer would be 24

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [reduce](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-core/Iterable/reduce.html). Like this:

```
List<int> number = [1, 2, 3, 4];
final result = number.reduce((value, element) => value * element);
```